# Can I chant these stotras without initiation?

Tags: mantras, stotra, shakti, sri-vidya

Can I chant 
1. [Mantra matruka stava](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/rAjarAjeshvarImantramAtRikAstava.html?lang=sa) and 2. [Mantra matruka pushpamala stava](http://www.svbf.org/journal/vol1no4/mantra.pdf)
without initiation as these contain panchadashi mantra (which is to be practiced only after initiation under the guidance of a guru as far as I know) and are named **mantra stavas**.

The second one is said to be written by Shri Adi Shankaracharya, I don't know about the first one. If some body has any clue as to who is the author of the first stava please let me know.

And also please let me know if there are any procedures to be followed if one decides to chant these stavas.

Comment: What is the problem with reciting the Stotra written by Adi Shankara?

Comment: @Rickross because it has letters of a mantra which are not to be changed without initiation

Comment: But that is not a problem as it does not explicitly contain the Mantra. Any Mantras are formed with the Matrika Varnas (the 51 Sanskrit alphabets) so there can be many such books/words/sentences that u read which might be containing all the letters of Panchadashi. IMO, it is always better to hv a Panchadashi initiation before reciting the first Stotra but the Adi Shankara written Stotra can be recited without worry. Why wd Adi Shankara compose a Stotra that can not be recited by everyone? Think in this way.

Comment: questions that ask for personal advice are not allowed on this forum. please read the forum rules.

Comment: Who was gaudapada s guru in sri vidya? How did he get the upadesham ?

Comment: If you can understand the meaning and relevance of mantra than only recite it without initiation. Guru's first duty is to teach you the meaning and relevance of a mantra

Comment: @Rickross //Why wd Adi Shankara compose a Stotra that can not be recited by everyone? //  What do you mean by this statement? And AFAIK there are more stotras composed by adi shankaracharya which contain mantras. For example, the shiva panchakshari stotra and the vaidhyanatha ashtakam, they both contain 'namah shivaaya' in each stanza. So does that mean we can chant them even without initiation like most people? Nothing wrong in that? 

Comment: Namah shivaya is a Vedic mantra but when it is dealt with in Tantras then the Tantric rules apply to its chanting not the Vedic rules (like women are not allowed) .. Similarly when Adi Shankara composed a Stotra having mantras then it has to be understood reciting the mantra while reciting the Stotra is allowed for everybody .. otherwise the Stotra itself must have stated that it should recited by only Dvijas @LSSJBroly

Comment: @Rickross So can you tell me about Panchakshari Stotram and vaidhyanatha ashtakam ? Do they require initiation and do these stotras state that only dwijas should chant it?  BTW your knowledge in the stotras and tantras field is outstanding. 

Comment: No they don't state that only Dvijas can recite them .. everyone can recite those Stotras .. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Thank you @Rickross 